# Justice League Mode - What does the 'x' meter indicate?

Tags: lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes

I have completed the story in Lego Batman 2: DC Heroes and unlocked the 'Justice League Mode' which involves beating waves of enemies with the different justice league characters.

I have noticed a sort of meter appear in the **top-right corner of the screen**, which wasn't there through the story (or free-play) missions, which looks like a grey circle with an 'X' symbol in it, and seems to fill up blue while playing. See the image below where I've marked the example.

[image: 'X' Meter Example]

What is this meter showing? What actions fills up (or potentially drains) the meter? What happens when the meter gets to full capacity?

I am playing the **PSVita** version of the game - however don't know if this meter appears in some form on the home console versions of the game.

I don't believe it was explained at any point, however the **PSVita** version does seem like a markedly cut-down version of what was created for the home consoles (as cut scenes don't quite match up to what I've just done sometimes, and they are low quality and compressed terribly).

Comment: Can you please give some feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

To my recognition it's some sort of meter to finish the area.

It has three stages shown in the images below

[image: Empty Meter] [image: Half Filled Meter] [image: Full Meter]

**(These Images are from the PSVita Version)**

You fight in the area with the heroes and it starts filling up as you defeat enemies.

Once you reach Full Meter and kill all enemies the area is cleared and you win.